# What is the width of a high altitude airway?

Tags: ifr-navigation, airways

Victor airways (airways that are below 18,000 ft) has a width of 8 NM. How about those airways that operates higher than 18,000 ft, do they have specific width you must be in?

Or is there no width because you would be using GPS? (ones with an RNP of 2 NM)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least in the US airspace definition, High Altitude Airways (Jet Routes) have no defined width regardless of the airway being navaid-based or RNAV/RNP

This is briefly stated in the FAA training manuals:
http://tfmlearning.faa.gov/Publications/atpubs/AIR/air2004.html

Answer (score 0):

There are several Navigation Performance Minima defined by ICAO. 
For example MNPS for the Atlantic Oceanic is 12,6NM later in 95% of time.
Since e.g. the Atlantic is a very bussy airspace, but without ground based Navigation Aids and communication to a controller is difficult, there is a incentive to improve the nav perf of aircraft. 
There are several regions (Shannon, Gander, New York, Santa Maria, Reykjavik) of wich a at least one has already adopted a MNPS 10 instead of MNPS 12,6.
The goal is to eventually reduce it to MNPS 4, but that might take a while.

In addition to that there is also vertical seperation, which up to FL 285 is normally 1000ft (semicircular flight rule).
From FL 290 it is 2000ft, exept in RVSM airspace (reduced vertical seperation minima), where it is 1000ft up to FL 410.
Above that vertical seperation is always 2000ft.

So a lot of planes fit into a quite small volume. Planes which can not satisfy these criteria are not allowed to fly within them.

Since I'm in the process if learning this stuff, I might have missed something or got something wrong, but it might give you an idea.